# Thumbnail url returns at the top of the page

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I wrote this simple shortcode to return my custom blog grid and I wanted to insert post featured image as the background image for post tile.

Everything works quite good except background image part. I cannot understand why image URL returns at the top of page and style attribute is empty it returns just `background-image url('');

Screenshot below:
[image]

```
function gita_blog_grid( $atts ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'perpage' => 3
  ), $atts ) );

  $output = '<div class="posts_wrapper"><div class="gita_posts_row">';
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'posts_per_page' => $perpage
  );

  $gita_query = new WP_Query ( $args );

  while($gita_query->have_posts()) : $gita_query->the_post();

      if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $post_thumb = the_post_thumbnail_url('full');
      }

      $output .= '<article class="gita_single_post" style="background-image: url(\''. $post_thumb . ' \')">';
      $output .= '<h3 class="gita_post_title">' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
      $output .= '</article></div></div>';

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $output;
  }

    add_shortcode('gita_blog', 'gita_blog_grid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail_url` displays the url directly to the page as soon as its called. In your case it is displaying the URL string directly to the screen as soon as its called, which is before you finish generating your output processing and returning it to be displayed.

Instead of displaying it directly, you want to get it as a variable so you need to use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` i.e.

```
 if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
       $post_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');
 }
```

**Ref:**

- [Codex for the_post_thumbnail_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url)
- [WP Developer Resource for get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)

Comment: Thank you for answer but this do not solve problem. Url returns in normal way, problem is that it goes at the top of page instead to the attribute. Edited answer with screenshot

Comment: Did you actually try it? Because I can guarantee you that it *is* whats causing the problem.

Comment: Maybe its cached then, because that is exactly whats happening. You can see that the site isn't using `get_the_post_thumbnail_url`: as you can see in the element inspector, the URL is not being added as the `gita_single_post` because your `$post_thumb` variable is empty... because the URL is being displayed at the top of the page instead of being saved into your variable!

Comment: Well, there is cache management plugin. This might be issue there - although i dump entire cache and it should not work while login as admin. 

Do you have perhaps any suggestion to solve this ? .

Comment: Resolved: Problem was $size = 'full' . When i deleted it url start to return in proper place. Still no clue why

Comment: Actually  no it do not work when i add full again. Just checked, it instantly brake and goes at the top of the page again.

Comment: Thats because the size is passed into `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` as the 2nd parameter - sorry, I forgot to change that part when I copied your code from your question. You need to pass the post id in as the first parameter - see the function link in the refs in my answer. I'll update the answer too for completeness.